# SQL Update query incorrect syntax near 'from'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

I have an update query

```
update w.ProblemNeed1
from WebReferrals w
left join TaxonomyCrosswalk tc ON w.ServiceTerm = tc.Service
set w.ProblemNeed1 = tc.ProblemNeed2
where w.ProblemNeed1 is null
```

This query got error near `FROM`. Can anyone correct me on this query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...? The `update` syntax does vary across databases.

Comment: As per the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), `set` comes before `from`. The official docs should always be the first place you search for your SQL syntax answers.

Comment: the `SET` parameter goes after the `UPDATE` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to illustrate the comments.

```
update w set ProblemNeed1 = tc.ProblemNeed2
from WebReferrals w
left join TaxonomyCrosswalk tc ON w.ServiceTerm = tc.Service
where w.ProblemNeed1 is null
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @ngoc Always happy to help